# Disabled javascript for printing?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

This may seem a strange question, but is it possible to disable javascript for the printed version of a webpage?

The reason being, it causes the printout's layout to all be on top of each other. But if I turn off javascript it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using print css, in the end I just set the containing div to display none, as it's not really needed.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using a special set of rules for printing, you can do this by specifying the `media` attribute in your style tag:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print" src="print.css" />
```

Comment: @Probocop is asking about javascript, not css

Comment: @Horse: and I was suggesting a more appropriate alternative.  If you need to disable JavaScript for a printed version of the page then you're doing something wrong.  In a comment on the question, the OP even says he went with this approach.